# Extract arrays of characters in String in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I've looked around and practiced my RegEx but I still can't get it right... Probably a noob question
How would I split a string to only keep the words (a to z) and only them, split by any other character?

```
hello3you ?! hey 32 foo
```

would return

```
["hello","you","hey","foo"]
```

I tried the following, no luck:

```
var words = itemObject["name"].toLowerCase().split(/^([a-z]+)/g);
var words = itemObject["name"].toLowerCase().split(/[a-zA-Z]+/g);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of splitting you should think of it as a matching operation; after all, the title of your question is about extracting strings:

```
'hello3you ?! hey 32 foo'.match(/[a-z]+/ig);
```

This will return an array of strings matching a "bunch of letters".

Comment: performance-wise, is it better, equal, or worse than all the split answers ?

Comment: @Stephane I don't think there's a significant difference in performance between the two; I personally find matching easier to reason with than splitting on the negative expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
[^a-z]+
```

You can split by this to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```js
var matches = "hello3you ?! hey 32 foo!".split(/[^a-z]+/).filter(function(el) {
  if (el.length) {
    return el;
  }
});

console.log(matches);
```

- `[^a-z]` is a range of characters that *are not* a-z (inclusive),
- `+` requires a match of one, or more, of those characters.

Comment: If you have a string like `"hello!"` this would yield an array with two elements, the last one being an empty string.

Comment: That's a good point; and suddenly I'm seeing why `match()` is the better option. I may, however, have added a slightly complex means of dealing with that.

Comment: This is where PHP's `preg_split()` has a slight advantage because it allows for a flag to skip empty segments :)

Answer (score 0):

try: `var words = itemObject["name"].toLowerCase().split(/([^a-z]+)/);`

Answer (score 0):

**Working:**

var words = itemObject["name"].match(/[a-z]+/ig);

**Output:**

```
hello,you,hey,foo
```